# Django Import Error using EC2 and bitnami

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I am trying to deploy my django app to amazon's ec2. I ran into some trouble getting my site-packages and my middleware working on the ec2 server. i am using bitnami djangostack for my AMI but am confused where on the server to put my site-packages (like registration south etc) and where to put my middleware (like pagination).

right now i am running the server and getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()

  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))

ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware pagination.middleware: "No module named pagination.middleware"
```

you can see the error at the following [link](http://ec2-67-202-59-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`site-packages` is not somewhere you manually add items. Let Python's installation tools - `pip` and `easy_install` do the job for you.

As for middleware, it can go anywhere that is in your `PYTHONPATH`. The best place to put it is in a file that is in one of your app's directory (same place you see `models.py`); typically this file is called `middleware.py`

If the middleware is part of a third-party application; first install that application. Typically this is done with `sudo easy_install package-name`. Use `sudo` to install it in the global python `site-packages` directory.

A better approach is to use a [virtual environment](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: is there no way to manually add items? i have a folder with all of the required site-packages on my local machine and i figured i could just add these to a folder on my server? is this not possible? thanks a lot burhan!

Comment: The problem with doing that is some packages may have optimized compiled code that may not work on your target server; also components like database drivers have other build requirements that need to be satisfied - they may install but won't work; which is why it is discouraged. You can execute `pip freeze > requirements.txt` on your development machine. This will list out all the packages. Then copy the `requirements.txt` file to your server and run `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`. This will install everything that was on your development machine on the server properly.